# ggplot doesn't display ending points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very simple data set consists of two columns:

```
dates,Edges
Aug 09 2012,787615368
Aug 14 2012,1135686707
Aug 24 2012,1177338668
Sep 10 2012,1227146408
Sep 21 2012,1256398473
Oct 04 2012,1287176222
Oct 19 2012,1325057099
Nov 02 2012,1601829854
Dec 07 2012,1703931041
Jan 16 2013,1896596589
Feb 25 2013,2080968491
Apr 01 2013,2264510866
Apr 26 2013,2372135083
Jun 20 2013,2604769625
```

and I use following code to plot each point in a x-y plane:

```
my_breaks = c("Aug 09 2012","Aug 14 2012","Aug 24 2012","Sep 10 2012","Sep 21 2012","Oct 04 2012",
              "Oct 19 2012","Nov 02 2012","Dec 07 2012","Jan 16 2013","Feb 25 2013","Apr 01 2013",
              "Apr 26 2013","Jun 20 2013")

snapshot_size_df$dates <- factor(snapshot_size_df$dates, levels = my_breaks)


ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data=snapshot_size_df, aes(dates, Edges, color='edges')) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position = "top", 
        legend.key = element_rect(fill=NA),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=16, angle=90), text = element_text(size=16), axis.text.y = element_text(size=16)) +
    theme(axis.line.y = element_line(color="grey40", size = .5)) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey", linetype = "dotted")) +
    labs(y = "Count", x="") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = my_breaks)
```

However, it doesn't display last three points:
[image]

UPDATE:
I should note that I use Jupyter Notebook to run my code. As two other people responded that the code works for them I tried to restart my session (kernel in the case of Jupyter Notebook) and my issue got fixed.

Comment: Works for me using R 3.4.1 and ggplot2 2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values are going off the chart, so you can set your `ylim`

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data=snapshot_size_df, aes(dates, Edges, color='edges')) +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position = "top", 
        legend.key = element_rect(fill=NA),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=16, angle=90), text = element_text(size=16), axis.text.y = element_text(size=16)) +
    theme(axis.line.y = element_line(color="grey40", size = .5)) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey", linetype = "dotted")) +
    labs(y = "Count", x="") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = my_breaks) + ylim(600000000, 3000000000)
```

Comment: still doesn't work! @bouncyball says it works for him/her. I might have a version issue!

Comment: That's strange. it worked for me too. So it seems like those values are missing for you? try restarting your session and make sure no other dataframes are using the same name.

Comment: You're right It works for me too when I use it in the terminal!! but I've still got an issue in Jupyter Notebook!

Comment: @Pymal This might be an issue with Jupyter Notebook, not R. `ggplot` has been funky when run within Jupyter Notebooks

Comment: As you suggested I restarted the session (kernel) and it worked. Thanks for your reply :)